# I ran "certbot delete --cert-name". Failed to restart Nginx

Tags: nginx, centos7, lets-encrypt, nginx-config, certbot

**environment**
・Nginx
・ CentOS 7
・ Certbot 0.31.0

---

```
$ sudo certbot delete --cert-name a.example.com

$ nginx -t
```

> 2019/04/13 01:19:30 [emerg] 10189 # 10189: BIO_new_file ("/ etc /
>   letsencrypt / live / a.example.com / fullchain.pem") failed (SSL :
>   error: 0200100D: system library: fopen: Permission denied: fopen
>   ('/etc/letsencrypt/live/a.example.com/fullchain.pem', 'r')   error:
>   2006D002: BIO routines: BIO_new_file: system lib) nginx: configuration
>   file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

```
$ sudo less /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
```

> FailedChallenges: Failed authorization procedure. A.example.com
>   (http-01): urn: ietf: params: acme: error: connection :: The server
>   could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http:
>   // a .example.com / .well-known / acme-challenge / xxxx: Connection
>   refused

---

Why are you trying to read the certificate though it should have been deleted?
How do I get Nginx to boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove only SSL certificate from letsencrypt path.

But it not remove SSL configuration from nginx configuration (in virtual host).

Edit you nginx config where was this certificate used.

Comment: The error was resolved when I edited the nginx config where this certificate was used!

Comment: where there files located?